# Can I connect a CM820 modem to a switch to get more ports?

Tags: modem, switch, switching

I have an [Arris Touchstone CM820 cable modem](http://www.arrisi.com/products/product.asp?id=74) (DOCSIS), but it has only one RJ45 socket. Can I connect a switch to it (like TL-SF1005D for example) in order to have more internet ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifications are not clear, but [the documentation](https://www.midcocomm.com/contentassets/b443bbd36fcf458a883231f34d6f24aa/arris-cm820a.pdf) says:

> **Ethernet Connection**
>
> [...] Note: To connect two or more computers to the Ethernet port, you will
>   need a hub or broadband router (available at computer retailers).
>
> [...] If you are connecting the
>   Cable Modem directly to a computer, or to an Ethernet hub or broadband
>   router with a cross-over switch, ask for Category 5e (CAT5e)
>   straight-through cable. CAT5e cable is required for gigabit Ethernet
>   (Gig-E), not regular CAT5 cable.

...and:

> **Making Ethernet Connections**
>
> 3. Connect one end of the yellow Ethernet cable to the yellow port on the back of the Cable Modem
>      labeled “Ethernet 10/100/1000,” [...] and the other end to the Ethernet
>      port on a computer, hub, or broadband router.

And as a [switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch) is merely an intelligent [hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_hub), switches are supported too.

However, this implies the modem must have a built-in DHCP server and router, but it also seems it has no administrative user interface to configure those? Of course, things can work fine with default settings, but to be a bit more sure you could [check the IP address](https://superuser.com/questions/92321/how-to-know-the-ip-address-of-a-mac-when-it-is-in-network) of your computer, to see if it's in [the private range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces). Seeing a private IP address is no 100% guarantee, but if it's *not* in the private range then your computer is connected to the internet directly. In that case a hub or switch is not good enough, and you'd need a [router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)) to give each computer its own local IP address.